# HBase split command throws NOT splittable error

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera

I tried to force split a region and received the following error.

```
ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: 3dd9ec2b32c98131b39fbfa8266881f9 NOT splittable                                                                                       
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.assignment.SplitTableRegionProcedure.checkSplittable(SplitTableRegionProcedure.java:193)                                                          
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.assignment.SplitTableRegionProcedure.<init>(SplitTableRegionProcedure.java:115)                                                                   
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.assignment.AssignmentManager.createSplitProcedure(AssignmentManager.java:750)                                                                     
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster$3.run(HMaster.java:1859)                                                                                                                  
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.procedure.MasterProcedureUtil.submitProcedure(MasterProcedureUtil.java:134)                                                                       
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.splitRegion(HMaster.java:1851)                                                                                                            
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterRpcServices.splitRegion(MasterRpcServices.java:808)                                                                                         
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$2.callBlockingMethod(MasterProtos.java)                                                             
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:413)                                                                                                                   
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:130)                                                                                                                  
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:324)                                                                                                        
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:304)
```

Anyone has insight about this error?

I am using Cloudera 6.1.1 and HBase 2.1.0.

Answer (score 5):

This is error returned when you trying to split:

- region  of `meta` table
- region which in CLOSED/CLOSING state
- region has references to other region(region which is result of recent split of other region)

I think, you faced last case.
When HBase split region it creates 2 new regions(children) and links it to region currently splitting(parent). Creating children regions more or less 'instant' operation which take a little time. This is due to files which contains data of parent region([store](https://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/StoreFile.html) files) not touched during split: HBase delays real split of data files until compaction. Before compaction, each child region contain only special [reference](https://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/io/Reference.html) to parent region data. Until this reference exists, region considered as 'not splittable'.

Comment: Is there any way to force compact those region reference files?

Comment: Try to compact these 2 new regions. This should remove links to parent